# youtube would not open in chromium

Tags: 15.04, flash, chromium

My YouTube and Flash video would not load on Chromium after doing an update. I have *flash plug-ins* installed as well as *pepper flash plug-ins*, and *adobe flash plug-ins* for Ubuntu 15.04.

How should I proceed so that Chromium will show Flash contents again?

Comment: I don't know Chromium, but could it be that you have any add-on for it that blocks scripts and objects, like NoScript for Firefox? You could also try reinstalling the package `flashplugin-installer` by running in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`. You maybe get prompted to accept the license there if that was missing. Then it should work again. Please leave me a comment containing "@ByteBOT" to notify me if that solved your problem, so that I can convert it to an answer.

Comment: YouTube uses HTML5 for videos, right?